# How to referencing a callback function on Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, callback, closures

**What I need?**

I need call a function from a class to close a `UIView` of another class when a event occurs. I've a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` and another class to manage the cells of that TableView.

My problem is when I try referencing the callback function inside `cellForRowAt`: `Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '(() -> ())?'`. I want call this callback on the `viewDidDisappear` method.

**Code**

```
class ViewControllerRelatorios : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var closeCellPopup : (()->())? // Ref

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewContent: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableViewContent.dataSource       = self
        self.tableViewContent.delegate         = self
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if closeCellPopup != nil {
            closeCellPopup!() // Here OK
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellDailyReport") as! CellDailyReport
       self.closeCellPopup = cell2.closePopup // Error: Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '(() -> ())?'
       return cell2
    }
}

class CellDailyReport : UITableViewCell {

    var lastView = UIView()

    var closePopup : () {
        self.lastView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

If I change declaration `var closeCellPopup : (()->())?` to `var closeCellPopup : ()?`, I can't call this function.

```
   override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if closeCellPopup != nil {
            closeCellPopup!() // Cannot call value of non-function type '()'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Btw this `if closeCellPopup != nil { closeCellPopup!() }` is useless. Just use `closeCellPopup?()` if it was `nil`, closure wouldn’t be called and code would run on

Comment: What is `closePopup` in your cell subclass supposed to be? It's not a function type

Comment: So, I'm make wrong it, but I must close the `UIView` cited on my code. How I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to do this, but you can fix your errors by making it a function.

```
class CellDailyReport : UITableViewCell {

    var lastView = UIView()

    func closePopup() {
        self.lastView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if your closure variable had the right type, your code still just would set reference of last dequeued cell.

If I understand it right, you need to remove every `lastView` from its superview after view controller did disappear, so you can just iterate through the downcasted cells of your table view

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let cells = tableViewContent.visibleCells as! [CellDailyReport]
    cells.forEach { $0.lastView.removeFromSuperView() }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution too, but @Callam's answer solve my problem in closed context of my situation.